# Ошибка 'error_code': 28, 'error_msg': 'Application authorization failed: this method is unavailable with service token.'

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Хочу выложить пост с помощью питон, но почему-то, вылезает ошибка:
`'error_code': 28, 'error_msg': 'Application authorization failed: this method is unavailable with service token.', 'request_params'`
Помогите пожалуйста разобраться в чем проблема.

```
import requests
import json

a = requests.post('https://api.vk.com/method/wall.post', data={
                                                              'domain': 'russianwelding',
                                                              'from_group': 1,
                                                              'message': 'Tets, test, test, tes',
                                                              'grant_type': 'password',
                                                              'v': 5.122,
                                                              'client_id': '7559962',
                                                              'client_secret': 'Security key',
                                                              'username': 'login',
                                                              'password': 'my_password'}).json()
print(a)
```

Comment: проблема в том, что `this method is unavailable with service token`

Comment: А как мне сделать, чтобы все заработало, просто я уже все перепробовал